# How to fix Error: "item' is not defined..."

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Its suppose return component that realize dropdown list by getting array of strings. Its probably some mistake how use elements of array.

```
import React from 'react'

class DropDownList extends React.Component {
  renderDropDownList = () => {
    const { dropDownDownData } = this.props
    return (
       <div className="book-shelf-changer">
       <select>
          dropDownDownData.map(function(item){
            <option key = {item} value={item}>{item}</option>
          })
        </select>
      </div>
    )

  }
  render() {
    const optionList  = ['Move to...','Currently Reading','Want to Read','Read','None']
    return this.renderDropDownList(optionList)
  }
}

export  { DropDownList }
```

Comment: try returning the entire `option` element -> Just add `return` in front of `<option key={item}...`. Also try `console.log(dropDownDownData)` to see if that variable is actually an array of strings, or whatever you expect

Comment: Why you wrote this const in curly braces?

Comment: @antdav That's destructuring assignment?

Comment: This is full of typos. 1) You forgot curly braces around the map for an inline JS expression. 2) You need to return from map callback

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just because you have forgotten some curly braces to call dropDownData function and your function is not interpreted as Javascript function. Add a return to your map function too.

It should work with this :

```
<select>
   {dropDownDownData.map(function(item){
      return (<option key = {item} value={item}>{item}</option>);
   })}
 </select>
```

You can also use ES6 syntax for your map expression :

```
 <select>
   {dropDownDownData.map(item => (<option key = {item} value={item}>{item}</option>))}
 </select>
```

Comment: I changed code... And browser write: _TypeError: dropDownDownData is undefined_